# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() and The mysqli extension is missing

Tags: php, mysql, iis, mysqli

1. I have below two in my php.ini file

   ```
   extension=php_mysql.dll
   extension=php_mysqli.dll
   ```
2. from the php.info(), can see below is correct.

   ```
   Loaded Configuration File   C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.ini
   ```
3. I have only one version php installed.

What else should I try?

The strange thing is, if I load my application the error is

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

but if I load phpMyAdmin, after login the error is

```
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
<a href="Documentation.html#faqmysql" target="documentation"><img class="icon" src="./themes/pmahomme/img/b_help.png" width="11" height="11" alt="Documentation" title="Documentation" /></a>
```

Comment: Using xampp or Easyphp or similar software can help o_o

Comment: If you've made any changes to any `.ini` / system files, then you need to restart all services including Apache. Add error reporting also. Try a fresh install also, if possible and make sure your file is `.php`. I noticed an `.html` link in there.

Comment: When you see, phpinfo is correct, do you mean, you see the 2 extensions in it? And don't forget, under windows, these dlls had dependecies, sometimes this cause the error: `libmysql.dll` and `libmysqli.dll` http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php

Comment: Hi, I'm using IIS. 
did iisreset, did mysql restart. problem not from here.

Comment: if you use xampp controll panel, then stop your Apache service & start again after your changes on php.ini file, like extension=php_mysql.dll extension=php_mysqli.dll

Comment: Hi lolka_bolka, I see neither extensions in my phpinfo display. Is that supposed to show up?
And I'm using php v5.3, so for the dlls dependecies(libmysql.dll), it not needed for this version. Am I right?

Comment: You should see the info in your phpinfo display. If not you need to restart the server.

Comment: Why I can't see extensions in my phpinfo? how to display those

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path to php.ini is set and is visible in 

at loaded configuration file.

if you are using windows.. make sure the use of / and  \ 
in apache httpd.conf
it should be 
PHPIniDir "C:/php/5.5/"